# Thread 1 Signal SIGBRT

Tags: xcode4.5

```
    #import
```

`#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}`

This is a thread 1 error that occurs when I press a specific button in the simulator.It crashes and gives this error.

Comment: for my hsc please help

Comment: can you see whats written on console window

Comment: it may be because you haven't set the outlet in xib or havent synthesize the button property

Comment: i have, i set the outlet in .h file and synthesized it in the .m

Comment: it has shown some error in console, Is there any? can you show the code.

Comment: is that what you wanted?

Comment: That's a warning, not the crash. Erase one Logo in your project file by removing the reference.

Your crash is something else, enable all exceptions:

Comment: ok thanks mate, do you know anything about the crash? Stephen J

Comment: delete default.png file

Comment: Search logo and default in your project ... You will find more than one file with same name so delete unnecessary file then clean and then build ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Project Navigator, select your Xcode Project file. This will show you the project settings as well as the targets in the project. Look in the "Copy Bundle Resources" Build Phase. You should find the offending files in that list twice. Delete the duplicate reference.

Xcode is complaining that you are trying to bundle the same file with your application two times.

Comment: that worked for the warnings! thank you very much but what about the crash?

Comment: Thanks, I worked it out. It was my web view, I had it pointing to the wrong directory within my app.